# Getting "ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer" when trying to SSH a remote Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, linode

I am very new to server managing. I have a Ubuntu 14.04 server set on Linode, according to the documentation, I can use `ssh root@97.107.137.168` to connect to the server. But when I do this in Terminal, I keep getting error message: `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`. I did a quick research for this message but couldn't get anything useful, so what could possibly be wrong?

**Edit**

My OS: OS X EI CAPITAN

SSH -V: OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.7

Comment: Which OS / ssh version you're using on the machine connecting from?

Comment: OS X EI CAPITAN. I am not aware that SSH has different versions, I just use the default Terminal.

Comment: Could you run `ssh -V` in your terminal and post the output? Did you had a look into this [thread](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151860/ssh-exchange-identification-read-connection-reset-by-peer)? Anything in there, which might help?

Comment: OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.7

Comment: If the peer closed the connection, then there should be information in the server logs. On the Linode admin interface you can get console access to your server. On an Ubuntu, the interesting information should be in /var/log/auth.

As for what the problem might be... do look at the thread suggested by @gf_

Comment: Note that Linode has been experiencing ongoing massive DDoS attacks since Christmas. Linodes in Atlanta have been more or less completely down since yesterday morning. Refer to http://status.linode.com/.